# Change the default From address in Outlook 2010/2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange-2010

I have a situation where a customer changed their primary SMTP domain.

Some users have send as rights to various mailboxes so they have the `From:` button displayed.
The From button displays the old primary address due to the profiles having been set up long before the address change took place.

The change was from name@old-ddmmain.com to name@new-domain.com

I'm hoping there's a registry entry that will allow a change for that email address to the new one, without having to create a new outlook profile.

The environment is Exchange 2010 SP3, clients are Outlook 2010.

Comment: Why don't you want to create a new outlook profile? They can continue use the old domain as the FROM without having a bounced delivery notice or successful delivery?

Comment: There are large number of users and the profiles work fine, email sent shows as coming from the new address, it's the address listed by the From button that has to change, it seems to be a static value set when the profile is created. It's actually an optics issue, but has to be solved without recreating profiles.

Comment: And all references to their previous account were full removed (not just reconfigured for the new domain) from Outlook?  Does the old domain/email address still exist in the Exchange server at all?

Comment: Can you clarify if you are looking to just change the name of the FROM address, or you looking to change the actual e-mail address the e-mail originates from. Do you want e-mail still sent from old-domain, but just display new-domain... or do you want e-mail to be sent from new-domain and have it display new-domain?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the same environment as you (Office 365 and Outlook 2013), so I will provide the steps I used to retrieve my answer. Your mileage may vary along with the usual caveats about the dangers of changing values in the registry directly versus using the application.

The change the e-mail name from Outlook 2013, I go to:

- File > Account Settings
- Select Account Settings from dropdown
- In Email tab, go to More Settings
- Change the e-mail name.

In my example, I added 01234567890 to my e-mail. You can see when I create a New Email, the name is appended with the numbers. This does not change the actual FROM e-mail Outlook 2013, but just the name.

[image]

For this sequence, I used [Process Monitor from SysInternals (procmon)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to monitor the file and registry activity where the process name contains outlook and category is write:

[image]

For me, I found that when I changed the e-mail address to the new value, this registry changed:

HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Profiles\Outlook\fc9a8ceae2b34f449fc525e570d01fcf

001f6620 = name@new-domain.com (Type = REG_BINARY)

[image]

Since you are using Outlook 2010, the registry path will be different, especially the 15.0 part.

Please be careful with remote registry changes. Always test first.

Answer (score 1):

I checked this with the same method as sunk818 but found slightly different results:

If you only change the value 001f6620 this will have the effect that if you go to the Account Settings afterwards, and try to change it manually, the change field, but only that will reflect your changes.

To also Update the  from adress name and account name I had to change the additional key "Account Name" for me (Outlook 2010) both keys were found under

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\Outlook\
```

in different subkeys. So far I have not found a really good method for identifying which subkey guid has to be used. The best I could come up with was either check all occurences of 001f6620 for the wrong mail or use the subkey that contains a key 001e6750 with value "Outlook".

For the Account Name it seems to be even harder. It is the only guid that has again several subkeys in the format "0000000X" and there for me it was the highest numbered one and the one containing a key "Identity Eid" that has a complex value including the words "exchange". It might be also wise to just iterate through all those folders and check all account names here.

Finally keep in mind that those are binary values and depending on the method you try to update those with the characters have to be spaced with trailing 00 because the binary format allows for formats that use more bits per character than ascii.

In conclusion I can only repeat sunk818's warning. I do not find registry changes in general to be problematic but in this case it's very hard to identify the correct keys and then they are even stored in non string format, so be very careful if you change things automatically here.

HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\Outlook\e6ee84559d879548bc05573166e74d21\001f6620

e6ee84559d879548bc05573166e74d21 = the folder where a REG_SZ 001e6750 with value Outlook exisists

HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-1874162390-2186939667-310645977-48933\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\Outlook\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676\00000003\Account Name

9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676 = The only folder containing subfolders

00000003 The folder where Identity Eid exists containing the value EXCHANGE